# Rails to heroku deploy issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I try to deploy my rails app to heroku. I get issue in logs.

2019-09-05T21:30:24.764421+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-05T21:30:24.764290 #10] DEBUG -- : [3adcd749-6637-4790-8b0d-dab833c46c47]   [1m[36mUser Create (16.1ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "note", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["name", ""], ["email", ""], ["note", ""], ["created_at", "2019-09-05 21:30:24.745537"], ["updated_at", "2019-09-05 21:30:24.745537"]]
2019-09-05T21:30:24.766999+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-05T21:30:24.766917 #10] DEBUG -- : [3adcd749-6637-4790-8b0d-dab833c46c47]   [1m[35m (2.0ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
2019-09-05T21:30:24.771504+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-05T21:30:24.771419 #10]  INFO -- : [3adcd749-6637-4790-8b0d-dab833c46c47] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 161ms (ActiveRecord: 47.8ms)
2019-09-05T21:30:24.772177+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-09-05T21:30:24.772096 #10] FATAL -- : [3adcd749-6637-4790-8b0d-dab833c46c47]
2019-09-05T21:30:24.772242+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-09-05T21:30:24.772179 #10] FATAL -- : [3adcd749-6637-4790-8b0d-dab833c46c47] Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):
2019-09-05T21:30:24.772293+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-09-05T21:30:24.772241 #10] FATAL -- : [3adcd749-6637-4790-8b0d-dab833c46c47]
2019-09-05T21:30:24.772375+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-09-05T21:30:24.772316 #10] FATAL -- : [3adcd749-6637-4790-8b0d-dab833c46c47] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `block in create'
2019-09-05T21:30:24.772377+00:00 app[web.1]: [3adcd749-6637-4790-8b0d-dab833c46c47] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23:in`create'
2019-09-05T21:30:24.727793+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=mailme-reminder.herokuapp.com request_id=3adcd749-6637-4790-8b0d-dab833c46c47 fwd="189.159.252.164" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=178ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2019-09-05T21:30:24.913280+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mailme-reminder.herokuapp.com request_id=df1321b0-44d2-46ef-9015-45a7f2fc8c38 fwd="189.159.252.164" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-09-05T21:31:09.129802+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-05T21:31:09.129668 #10]  INFO -- : [17ce6b70-1cd1-4b7e-b7b8-2a8b79f09643] Started GET "/" for 189.159.252.164 at 2019-09-05 21:31:09 +0000
2019-09-05T21:31:09.131458+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-05T21:31:09.131337 #10]  INFO -- : [17ce6b70-1cd1-4b7e-b7b8-2a8b79f09643] Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2019-09-05T21:31:09.138108+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-05T21:31:09.138004 #10]  INFO -- : [17ce6b70-1cd1-4b7e-b7b8-2a8b79f09643]   Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-09-05T21:31:09.142089+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-05T21:31:09.142006 #10]  INFO -- : [17ce6b70-1cd1-4b7e-b7b8-2a8b79f09643]   Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
2019-09-05T21:31:09.144723+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-05T21:31:09.144626 #10]  INFO -- : [17ce6b70-1cd1-4b7e-b7b8-2a8b79f09643] Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 9.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2019-09-05T21:31:09.101818+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mailme-reminder.herokuapp.com request_id=17ce6b70-1cd1-4b7e-b7b8-2a8b79f09643 fwd="189.159.252.164" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=5496 protocol=https
2019-09-05T21:31:26.058494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=mailme-reminder.herokuapp.com request_id=63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e fwd="189.159.252.164" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=26ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2019-09-05T21:31:26.085304+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-05T21:31:26.085200 #14]  INFO -- : [63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e] Started POST "/users" for 189.159.252.164 at 2019-09-05 21:31:26 +0000
2019-09-05T21:31:26.086465+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-05T21:31:26.086388 #14]  INFO -- : [63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e] Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
2019-09-05T21:31:26.086570+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-05T21:31:26.086505 #14]  INFO -- : [63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DNicK64JMa2ApcaSeYrP84zdeZe7hDYc2HZktB0ObXp4IVmCobV4KJQnZ9UazBiROfn6sE/jsCredCh6HzMgwg==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Michael", "email"=>"example_email@example.com", "date_and_time"=>"2019/09/05 17:00", "note"=>"Check"}, "commit"=>"Remind Me"}
2019-09-05T21:31:26.092268+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-05T21:31:26.092172 #14] DEBUG -- : [63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e]   [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
2019-09-05T21:31:26.096930+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-05T21:31:26.096826 #14] DEBUG -- : [63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e]   [1m[36mUser Create (1.8ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "note", "date_and_time", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["name", "Michael"], ["email", "example_email@example.com"], ["note", "Check"], ["date_and_time", "2019-09-05 22:00:00"], ["created_at", "2019-09-05 21:31:26.092480"], ["updated_at", "2019-09-05 21:31:26.092480"]]
2019-09-05T21:31:26.099330+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-05T21:31:26.099250 #14] DEBUG -- : [63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e]   [1m[35m (2.0ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
2019-09-05T21:31:26.102570+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-05T21:31:26.102493 #14]  INFO -- : [63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)
2019-09-05T21:31:26.103205+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-09-05T21:31:26.103127 #14] FATAL -- : [63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e]
2019-09-05T21:31:26.103267+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-09-05T21:31:26.103206 #14] FATAL -- : [63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e] Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):
2019-09-05T21:31:26.103318+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-09-05T21:31:26.103263 #14] FATAL -- : [63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e]
2019-09-05T21:31:26.103376+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-09-05T21:31:26.103323 #14] FATAL -- : [63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `block in create'
2019-09-05T21:31:26.103377+00:00 app[web.1]: [63bbddba-107e-47b5-a0ee-ca8da83a6b0e] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23:in`create'

Comment: Have you read [the page both messages link to](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support your case, you must use `s3` as they mentioned in their doc https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku here, else you will end up missing image after the instance restarted or after you deploy new version.

> The files will go away when the app is deployed, or when it is automatically restarted (once every 24 hours)

There's no other better option, you can either:

1. Keep using heroku for the server and s3 for file storage (No charge for free tier, just keep a reminder to shut it down sometimes later)
2. Move all to AWS, so you don't have to use 2 providers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not actually using Active Storage, look in Config > Environments > production.rb and you should find the following lines;

```
# Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

Just comment out `config.active_storage.service = :local` to make it look like this:

```
# Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
# config.active_storage.service = :local
```

Or, remove both lines entirely.

Then, it should work fine on Heroku.

Comment: What happens by default when that line isn't in the file? Doesn't OP need to [configure another location](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup), e.g. to store files on Amazon S3? And if so, don't they need to create a bucket and configure authentication?

Comment: @Chris Well, I'm not quite sure why but one of my application has it commented out by default and the one I had running on Heroku doesn't have it at all. I am able to still have images saved locally on both apps too so it may have been uncommented by mistake. It's an error that Heroku is throwing probably due to Heroku's local servers and how they are responding to it being uncommented.

Comment: "the one I had running on Heroku doesn't have it at all"—if you're not using Active Storage that would make sense. OP is likely using it based on their question.

Comment: @Chris Hmm, I may not be too familiar with what Active Storage really is then. Good point though, it would make sense why it is uncommented.

Comment: The page I linked to in my first comment gives a pretty good overview. And the page linked to in OP's error message, which I asked if they've read in my other comment, specifically talks about how to set it up on Heroku.

Comment: I did this one ''# Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  # config.active_storage.service = :local ???'' but it's still not working

Comment: @MichaMichael, `:local` is the _problem_, not the solution. And it's what you had at the beginning (see what it says in the warning?) so why would that change anything?

Comment: now I can open the main page but when I want to send the form by pressing the button I get "We're sorry, but something went wrong.." In local server all works good.

Comment: @MichaMichael What are your error messages? Enter `heroku logs --tail` in your command/terminal window and let us know what went wrong when you tried submitting the form.